# Comparing terms of two infinite series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Given  that $a_n\gt 0$ and  $b_n \gt 0$ $\forall n\in \mathbb N$ .
 Also $${a_{n+1}\over a_n}\le {b_{n+1}\over b_n}.$$  To  prove  that $\ \ $*If $\sum b_n$  converges  then  so  does  $\sum a_n$*

and $\ \ $ *If $b_n\rightarrow 0$ then so  does $a_n$*

Since  it  is  an  exercise  for  **comparison test** , I'm guessing that  the  given  condition should  somehow  means that $a_n\le b_n.$  But  how  do  I  prove  that  $?$  Please  help.

Comment: You need not have $a_n \leqslant b_n$. But what do you know about $\dfrac{a_n}{a_0}$?

Comment: @DanielFischer : Nothing . It  does  not mention  whether  $a_n$  is  increasing  or  decreasing or  anything . Just  *non-negative* it is.

Comment: (Strictly positive, not only non-negative.) You can derive something from the given condition. Compare with $\dfrac{b_n}{b_0}$.

Comment: @DanielFischer : Okay . So , I  get  $a_n \le {\left(a_0 \over b_0\right)}{\cdot b_n}$ or $a_n \le C . b_n$ . So  comparison  test  immediately  works  $?$

Comment: Yes, it's plain comparison now.

Answer (score 1):

As stated by [Daniel Fischer ♦](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/83702/daniel-fischer) in the comments:

$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\leq\frac{b_{n+1}}{b_n}$ can be rearranged to form $\frac{a_{n+1}}{b_{n+1}}\leq\frac{a_n}{b_n}$.

This means that:

$\frac{a_n}{b_n}\leq\frac{a_{n-1}}{b_{n-1}}\leq\frac{a_{n-2}}{b_{n-2}}\leq\dots\leq\frac{a_0}{b_0}$

As such, $a_n\leq\frac{a_0}{b_0}b_n=C\times b_n$ (for some constant $C$), so by limit comparison test, $\sum a_i\leq C\times\sum b_i$. Hence $\sum a_i$ converges.